# Motor heating up when I change the speed of the PWM generator in my SVPWM

Tags: power-electronics, pwm, motor-controller, vector-control

I am trying to implement a current control loop in my PMSM motor using SVPWM. Currently I am running an open loop control using lookup table values for V and F for changing the PWM duty cycle. Now I want to measure the current change as the speed of the motor changes. But when I try to increase the speed of the motor it heats up rather drastically. The motor is rating at 108 V. Currently I am supplying it 40 Vac which comes to 11 V at the motor output.

I am currently in my testing phase therefore I am driving it at low voltage because I am afraid the circuit might blow up or the motor might burn if I increase the voltage. What should I do?

Comment: Please share voltage and current waveforms.